# regex part of url

Tags: php, regex

So I'm trying to get the id from a url for youtube..

here is the url

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kffacxfA7G4/related?v=2`

then there's also - in the url too.

it wouldn't let me post another url but it's the same as above but with the id ucvkO0x-mL4

how can I grab between videos/ and /related (the id) with regex?

I tried to use txt2re.com which is what I always use, but it's not working for this case..

thanks!

Comment: Try adding the second URL enclosed in backticks, like I did to the first one.  (I could add it myself, but I want to know if it will let *you* add it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for even regex, just a simple `strpos` and `substr` will do it. Or just use `explode` like this:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kffacxfA7G4/related?v=2';

//BY STRPOS/SUBSTR
echo substr($url, 42, strpos($url, '/related', 42) - 42);

//BY EXPLODE
$parts = explode('/', $url);
echo $parts[6];
?>
```

Comment: +1, but I liked the answer more before the `explode` approach.

Comment: @sberry2A, OK I have added `strpos` method too.

Answer (score 1):

`(?:.*)videos/(.*?)/related\?v=2`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kffacxfA7G4/related?v=2';
preg_match('#.*videos/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]{11})/related.*#', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But, @shamittomar is right about `strpos` and `substr`

Answer (score 0):

using regex you can do it by

$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kffacxfA7G4/related?v=2";

preg_match('/videos\/(.+)\/related/',$url,$match);

$id = $match[1];